# Nested footnotes with Octopress

Tags: markdown, jekyll, octopress, rdiscount

Which, if any, octopress plugins support nested footnotes?

The default install uses rdiscount, which doesn't support footnotes that have footnotes.

If nothing has direct support, I may try using pandoc to convert TeX to markdown. That seems a bit convoluted, though.